# Microsoft Teams installation script coming everytime during startup in Windows 11

Tags: microsoft-teams

Microsoft Teams installation script coming every time during startup in Windows 11. Tried uninstallation of Teams many a times. Also removed from startup but still it is appearing.

Answer (score 1):

If you deployed Microsoft Teams through group policy. Try to disable the policy and then try. Gpupdate both side and restart the client pc after restart.